# how to make a mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql

I am kind of a beginner in java , and i've made a java application that uses mysql as backend. I run it in my localhost currently. I've made all the required database with necessary tables and some junk values using the phpmyadmin page ,so that i can see its working. So my doubt is that when i'll send this .jar to a friend who has a mysql installed system ,he will be able to run it, but how could he use all the database and tables that i've created only for my localhost?
Is there anyway i can send him the database i created along with the jar file so that those db also gets added on his localhost, or is there anyway i can code it inside my java app to create a new mysql db with all required tables and values when its been run the first time.
Apologies,if this seems like a noobish question.

Comment: You could export the database as a script for them to load

Comment: backup/export a dump file and send that to your friend he will import it and will have all the tables and data

Comment: as alternative way you can use portable db like SQLite, the query is almost same..

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting data from your database and send the `dump sql file`, user can import that sql file in there database.

**Export:**

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > alldb.sql
```

**Import:**

```
mysql -u root -p < alldb.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two method to do above task.

1- Create table/database at the time of starting of application, if table/db exist then skip or create all necessary db/tables according to your requirement.

2- You can take dump of all database. To take dump follow below.

If you are using windows then open command prompt or if you are on linux then open shell terminal and run following query with below syntex.

```
mysqldump databas_name --user=mysql_user_name --password=mysql_password >path_to_save
```

e.g.

```
mysqldump test --user=root --password=root >D:\tes.sql
```

Now you can restore above sql file on any other system in mysql.

```
mysql test --user=root --password=root <D:\tes.sql
```

Comment: consider i dumped the needed db with all tables to a directory and i send it to my friend along with my jar. is it possible to restore that dumped db files to their localhost automatically through the prog. itself w/o any manual procedure for the users....

Comment: you can do with both option as mention above with mysql command or else with as command execution in java.